# Residuals calculation in series with few points (max 20)

Tags: r, loess

I'm using `loess` to calculate the residuals. I expect for the following (small series) to find a big value of the residual for the third point

```
    y <- c(5814, 6083, 17764, 6110, 6556)
    x <- c(14564, 14719, 14753, 14754, 15086)
    > residuals(loess(y ~ x))
            1             2             3             4             5 
 2.728484e-12 -9.094947e-13  3.637979e-12  3.637979e-12  0.000000e+00
```

In particular,  `loess` gives the following output:

```
> loess(y ~ x)
Call:
loess(formula = y ~ x)

Number of Observations: 5 
Equivalent Number of Parameters: 5 
Residual Standard Error: Inf 
Warning messages:
1: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  :
  span too small.   fewer data values than degrees of freedom.
2: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  :
  pseudoinverse used at 14561
3: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  :
  neighborhood radius 191.61
4: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  :
  reciprocal condition number  0
5: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  :
  There are other near singularities as well. 1.1263e+005
```

There is probably a (very simple) reason that I'm missing now, but the above seems strange to me... why it "doesn't work" as expected in my case?

EDIT:

thanks to @Gavin Simpson who suggested me this [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Robust.html) I found out in the package `MASS` the function `rlm` which gives exactly what I was hoping.In the mean time I also tried to use `lowess` with several iteration and its fitted values converged actually "better" (in this case) to my data:

```
library(MASS)
method_rlm <- rlm(x=x,y=y)
method_lowess <- lowess(x,y, iter=7, f=1)

df<-data.frame(x=x, y=y, rlm=method_rlm$fitted.values, lowess=method_lowess$y)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y), color="red") +
  geom_line(aes(x, rlm), color="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(x, lowess), color="green") +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), color="red")
```

[image]

I also had a look to some timings and the difference is huge..

```
> microbenchmark(rlm(x=x,y=y), lowess(x,y, iter=7, f=1), times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
                          expr      min       lq    median        uq        max neval
             rlm(x = x, y = y) 6445.269 6663.972 6906.1350 9417.1895 271494.006  1000
 lowess(x, y, iter = 7, f = 1)  169.099  193.046  238.0085  273.9295   3900.493  1000
```

do you think this difference will be worth? I have million of small series like that ( with 5 to 20 points maximum and similar type of outliers)

Comment: What seems strange to me is trying to fit a quadratic smoother to fewer than 5 data points. What did you expect?

Comment: @joran I written above... `a big value of the residual for the third point` any idea to help?

Comment: None of the residuals are big. They are all essentially zero.

Comment: @joran yes I can see. I meant that, being 4 of those 5 points almost in straight line and the other way out of trend, I was expecting a relatively high residuals for only that point

Comment: Why would you expect that? Do you even know what a loess smoother does?

Comment: the function in details not but, plotting `$fitted` it seems it averages each point with its neighbors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 5 observations in the data and `loess()` is fitting a model with 5 degrees of freedom, hence it is able to fit the observed data perfectly and thence the small (effectively 0) residuals. `loess()` has sufficient freedom to interpolate your data exactly, but is not a useful summary of the data. Fit a simpler model.

Comment: hi thanks for the explanation, now it makes much sense. is there a way to manually set the degree of freedom? I tried to modify `span` from the default (0.75) to 1 and I didn't get any warning.

Comment: That will have reduced the effective degrees of freedom but the fit may be poor. Anyway, if you want more control on exact degrees of freedom then `smooth.spline` might be a start; see its `df` argument. But you are asking a lot for a spline to fit a single outlier without being affected - you probably want something robust instead.

Comment: mmm ok thanks again! regarding your last sentence, do you eventually know some methods already implemented in `R`?

Comment: There is a robust GAM package IIRC [**robustgam**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustgam/index.html), and you could look for more in the [**Robust** task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Robust.html). Note also that `loess()` has `family = "symmetric"` which may be more robust (though do read `?loess` for a cautionary note), but which doesn't help much with these data.

Comment: I actually don't want to fit the outlier... that's why I was expecting an higher residual for that point. anyway, that's for all!!

Comment: Then you really do need robust methods; standard methods will be terribly upset by the gross outlier as you have found.