# geom_smooth not working/showing anymore after adding more data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I pull data from a database every week and plot some charts using ggplot2. This week `geom_smooth` is not showing up anymore. When I remove the last record it works, why?

**Sample Data**

```
data <- structure(list(Status = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Cancelled", 
"Closed", "In SAP", "Open"), class = "factor"), Year_Month = c("2017-06", 
"2017-07", "2017-08", "2017-09", "2017-10", "2017-11", "2017-12", 
"2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", 
"2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-10", 
"2018-11"), CNT = c(63L, 52L, 66L, 45L, 47L, 49L, 42L, 44L, 48L, 
67L, 46L, 46L, 58L, 41L, 50L, 45L, 57L, 29L, 19L, 46L), per = c(67.74, 
71.23, 70.97, 71.43, 78.33, 71.01, 63.64, 67.69, 53.93, 73.63, 
60.53, 54.76, 81.69, 69.49, 63.29, 70.31, 69.51, 33.33, 23.17, 
52.87), date = structure(c(17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 
17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 
17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17805, 17836), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Status", 
"Year_Month", "CNT", "per", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Year_Month", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, c(16L, 18L), c(17L, 19L)), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(Year_Month = c("2017-06", 
"2017-07", "2017-08", "2017-09", "2017-10", "2017-11", "2017-12", 
"2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", 
"2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Year_Month", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Year_Month"))
```

**Plot with 20 records**

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=date, y=per)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Status),size=3) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess',aes(group=data$Status, color=Status))
```

[image]

**Plot with 19 records**

```
data <- head(data,19)
```

[image]

Comment: (a) _never_ use `$` in `aes()` unless you _really_ know what you're doing; (b) ggplot2 does some heuristics in `geom_smooth` and knows enough to not try to do the loess computation when there's only one data point but isn't smart enough to not do it when there is more than 1. You likely got many warnings when you ran it with the whole data set and the errors are pretty clear. You will have to write a validation step before you plot. Another option is to `facet_wrap(~Status)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr that was not the cause, bu thanks for the tip

Comment: Correct the  `$` was not the cause but it's really bad practice and it needed to be pointed out so others do not think it is good practice. Using the `facet_wrap` "hack" calls separate computation function in ggplot2 and doesn't cause the smoothing operations to die a horrible death.

Comment: It has to do with your `Open` group only having 2 points. You can't smooth between 2 points, or with fewer points than degrees of freedom. See `warnings()` and this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840593/residuals-calculation-in-series-with-few-points-max-20

Comment: Which is a rephrase of the first comment @Anonymouscoward.

Comment: I have data sets that have 2 or 3 `Open` status records and `geom_smooth` did work on the other ones and ignored the `Open` records. Is there any way that I can make this work without using `facet_wrap`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Those must have been edits, only the `aes()` bit was there.

Comment: Correction: going back to the previous plots, `geom_smooth` works with 1 or 3 records, but not with 2, very interesting and disappointing at the same time!

Comment: @Ibo write a validation step and if it detects there's insufficient # of elements in a group, separate the data frame by groups and make separate plots with ones with sufficient #'s using smoothing and the others not.

Comment: you shouldn't use it with 3. it's pretty meaningless without a decent, representative sample

Comment: I excluded `open` from the data and it worked. Thanks for the pointers guys!

Comment: Not sure why I've been accused of plagiarism, of a comment no less, but I find it unjustified and antagonistic. The first comment was `never use $ in aes() unless you really know what you're doing`, and is even reflected by OP's response to just that statement. Anyway, sorry to have to redress that here but I'm glad you got some solid answers Ibo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do/show, you can either:

1) Only use `geom_smooth` with groups where you have enough data, by specifying the `data` argument in the call

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=date, y=per)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Status),size=3) +
  geom_smooth(data = data %>% filter(Status != "Open"), method = 'loess', aes(color = Status))
```

or

2) Use `geom_smooth` on all the data together

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=date, y=per)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Status),size=3) +
  geom_smooth(data = data, method = 'loess')
```

The warnings you saw (per @hrbrmstr's comments) are from the `loess` function. I'd check out `?loess`. It's always helpful to know what's behind your plots.

Answer (score 3):

As a general solution, one can do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

min_number <- 5    # set this to something reasonable of your choice

ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = per, color = Status)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_smooth(
    data = . %>% group_by(Status) %>% filter(n() >= min_number),
    method = 'loess'
  )
```

To only plot smooths for groups with at least `min_number` of observations.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments `geom_smooth` cannot handle 2 elements in the status group of `Open`. Interestingly, it is ok with 1 or 3 elements. To solve the problem I decided to exclude `Open` from the data and it worked without any problem.

```
data2 <- data %>% dplyr::filter(Status!="Open")

ggplot(data,aes(x=date, y=per)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Status),size=3) +
  geom_smooth(data=data2,method = 'loess',aes(group=Status, color=Status))
```

Comment: Probably makes sense to use @zack's answer

Comment: @BenG Axeman's answer is better to be honest, but I upvoted both guys for their help